# Import Data Efficiently from Datastore to BigQuery every Hour - Python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore

Currently, I'm using Google's 2-step method to backup the datastore and than import it to BigQuery.
I also reviewed the code using pipeline. 
Both methods are not efficient and have high cost since all data is imported everytime.
I need only to add the records added from last import.

What is the right way of doing it?
Is there a working example on how to do it in python?

Answer (score 3):

You can look at [Streaming inserts](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery). I'm actually looking at doing the same thing in Java at the moment.

If you want to do it every hour, you could maybe add your inserts to a pull queue (either as serialised entities or keys/IDs) each time you **put** a new entity to Datastore.  You could then process the queue hourly with a cron job.

Comment: That's an interesting direction @tx802. I've done streaming inserts in the past but didn't use pull queue to group inserts which is reasonable.  But what about another option - reading from datastore with cursor and using it to start from last record fetched in previous hourly cron call. The cursor can be saved in Memcache or Datastore. This may save the need of pull queue.

Comment: Off the top of my head I'm wondering if there's a possibility the cursor may be stale after an hour.  i.e., depending on the query you use to iterate your entities, is there a chance you created new entities 'before' the point where the cursor is currently pointing? (Not sure I'm explaining it well.)

Answer (score 2):

There is no full working example (as far as I know), but I believe that the following process could help you :

1- You'd need to add a "last time changed" to your entities, and update it.

2- Every hour you can run a MapReduce job, where your mapper can have a filter to check for last time updated and only pick up those entities that were updated in the last hour

3- Manually add what needs to be added to your backup.

As I said, this is pretty high level, but the actual answer will require a bunch of code. I don't think it is suited to Stack Overflow's format honestly.

Comment: If the filtering is done in the mapper than I still need to read all records and that is still a problem. According to the documentation of DatastoreInputReader: "This reader does no filtering: you would need to do any required filtering in your mapper.". Am I missing something here?

Comment: OH you're trying to not read at all. I assumed it was the copy you wanted to skip.  Yeah in that case, tx's solution might be a better fit

Comment: I want to prevent extra reads of already processed records since it  increases price significantly when you have high volume datastore entity.  I found your answer useful anyway since I do see in the DatastoreInputReader source code reference to filters implementation but without proper formal documentation I can't touch it. I will be happy if someone can clarify this. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The Mapreduce docs a out of date. If you specify your mapper params like this: params = {"input_reader" : {
                                "entity_kind" : "my_entities.Blah",
                                 "filters" : filters
                                }                                 
                            },

Where the filters are a list of tuples filters.append(("disabled", "=", False)) then it will only send the entities that match the filter to the mapper.